# Connect points from set in the line segments

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I have been given a task where I have to connects all the points in the 2D plane. 
There are four conditions to to be met:

1. Length of the all segments joined together has to be minimal.
2. One point can be a part of only one line segment.
3. Line segments cannot intersect
4. All points have to be used(one can't be left alone but only if it cannot be avoided)

Image to visualize the problem: 
[image]

The wrong image connected points correctly, although the total length is bigger that the the one in on the left.

At first I thought about sorting the points and doing it with a sweeping line and building a tree of all possibilities, although it does seem like a way to complicated solution with huge complexity. Therefore I search better approaches. I would appreciate some hints what to do, or how could I approach the problem.

Comment: I don't know too much about it, but what if you started with a k-means analysis (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) where `k = n/2`? `n` being the number of points. Running k-means on your example seemed to produce the correct result every time I tried it. Do you have more solved examples with larger collections of points?

Answer (score 1):

I would start with a Delaunay triangulation of the point set. This should already give you the nearest neighbor connections of each point without any intersections. <del>In the next step I'd look at the triangles that result from the triangulation - the convenient property here is that based on your ruleset you can pick exactly one side from each triangle and remove the remaining two from the selection.</del>

<del>The problem that remains now is to pick those edges that give you the smallest total sum which of course will not always be the smallest side since that one might already have been blocked by a neighboring triangle. I'd start with a greedy approach, always picking the smallest remaining edge that has not been blocked by neighboring triangles yet.</del>

**Edit:** In the next step you retrieve a list of all the edges in that triangulation and sort them by length. You also make another list in which you count the amount of connections each point has. Now you iterate through the edge list going from the longest edge to the shortest one and check the two points it connects in the connection count list: if each of the points has still more than 1 connection left, you can discard the edge and decrement the connection count for the two points involved. If at least one of the points has only one connection left, you have got yourself one of the edges you are looking for. You repeat the process until there are no edges left and this should hopefully give you the smallest possible edge sum.

If I am not mistaken this problem is loosely related to the knapsack problem which is NP-Hard so I am not sure if this solution really gives you the best possible one.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say this is an extension to the well-known **travelling salesman problem**.

A good technique (if a little old-fashioned) is to use a **simulated annealing** optimisation technique.

You'll need to make adjustments to the cost (a.k.a. *objective*) function to miss out sections of the path. But given a candidate continuous path, it's reasonably trivial to decide which sections to miss out to minimise its length. (You'd first remove the longer of any intersecting lines).

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that's a tricky one.  That's a lot of conditions to meet.

I think from a programming standpoint, the "simplest" solution might actually be to just loop through, find all the possibilities that satisfy the last 3 conditions, and record the total length as you loop through, and just choose the one with the shortest length in the end - brute force, guess-and-check.  I think this is what you were referring to in your OP when you mentioned a "sweeping line and building a tree of all possibilities".  This approach is very computationally expensive, but if the code is written right, it should always work in the end.

If you want the "best" solution, where you want to just solve for the single final answer right away, I'm afraid my math skills aren't strong enough for that - I'm not even sure if there is any single analytical solution to that problem for any arbitrary collection of points.  Maybe try checking with the people over at [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/).  If someone over there can explain you with the math behind that calculation, and you then you still need help to convert that math into code in a certain programming language, update your question here (maybe with a link to the answer they provide you) and I'm sure someone will be able to help you out from that point.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions is to use graph theory.

Construct a bipartite graph G, such that each point has its copy in both parts. Now put the edges between the points `i and j` with the `weight = i == j ? infinity : distance[i][j]`. The minimal weight maximum matching in the graph will be your desired configuration.

Notice that since this is on a euclidean 2D plane, the resulting "edges" of the matching will not intersect. Let's say that edges `AB` and `XY` intersect for points `A, B, X, Y`. Then the matching is not of the minimum weight, because either `AX, BY` or `AY, BX` will produce a smaller total weight without an intersection (this comes from triangle inequality a+b > c)